# Rarefaction curves in RStudio. How do I add labels to the end of the lines?

Tags: r, vegan

I am using R to do a simple rarecurve, it makes a nice graph and i can colour and add lables to the axis or title. But I can not get it to show the plot labels.

Someone help?

Below is what I started with.

```
library(vegan)
rarecurve(orders, step=1, xlab="Individuals", ylab="Orders")
```

When I change

```
rarecurve(orders, step=1, xlab="Individuals", ylab="Orders", label=TRUE)
```

Nothing changes on the graph. I just want a label at the end of each plot saying what row it is from?

I've seen others who have used Vegan and gotten lables on their data, I have tried copying exactly what they have done and I still get no labels. Is there something with the data I need to change?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you also include sample data in your question so we can run your code. See [how to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to those who viewed my question. For those of you who are also new here is the answer! Hopefully it saves you 12 hours of your life..

I made sure the excel file I used had row names in the first column. Then when loading the data into R I used:

dataname<-read.csv(file="nameofexcel.csv", header = TRUE, row.names=1)

This last bit was not explained and took a lot of playing to figure out. Sorry it is a amateur error but that is what we all are when we start out. Well many of us.